# Laravel many relation insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I need to add array to the database table. In HTML I'm using select with multiple select values.

My code:
HTML Like as:

```
<select name="sel_val[]" multiple>
                                <optgroup label="select_values">
                                    @foreach($val as $v)
                                    <option value="{{$v->id}}">{{$v->text}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
```

model relation like as:

```
public function relationtest(){


        return $this->hasMany('App\test',"testid","id");
    }
```

And controller:

```
protected function create(Request $request){
    $last = Home::create([
        'somename'=>$request['somename'],
        'text'=>$request['text']
    ]);


    $last->relationtest()->createMany([

            'selectvalue'=>$request->sel_val
        ]);


    return Redirect::to('admin/products');
}
```

My array (print_r($request)):

```
 [sel_val] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )
```

And DB

```
HOME::
|id|sometext|text
|1 |asdgasdg|gsdg
|2 |asdgdsdg|gsg

TEST::
|id|selectvalue|testid

//testid == HOME::id
```

in short, I need to $request->sel_val(array) has been added to the database. I think I should use "createMany" but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify just use something like this:

```
$values = $request->get('sel_val');

foreach ($values as $value)
{
    $last->relationtest()->create(['selectvalue' => $value]);
}
```

If you want to optimize it to one query, sure, you could use createMany:

```
$values = $request->get('sel_val');
$toCreate = [];

foreach ($values as $value)
{
    $toCreate[] = ['selectvalue' => $value];
}

$last->relationtest()->createMany($toCreate);
```

Comment: Basically just treat relationships the same as eloquent or query builder objects. Most methods will work the same, such as update, insert, create, delete, ect.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models
https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent